# What is the main difference between include, use and extend in Symfony2?

Tags: php, symfony, frameworks

I am learning Symfony2 framework for development and couldn't find any proper explanation.

An explanation with example will be very helpful.

Comment: Have you looked at the twig manual (as opposed to the Symfony docs?  The twig manual goes into more detail.

Answer (score 3):

When to use include:

> Out of the 50 pages, there are 6 pages that share a chunk of HTML -
>   you create a shared-chunk.twig and include it in those 6 pages.

When to use inheritance:

> You have 50 pages sharing the same layout - you create a layout.twig
>   as a parent, and each page extends that layout.twig. So the parent is
>   the generic and the child is the specific.

usage in another way :

> You notice that your layout.twig is bit cluttered and you would like
>   to modularize it, so you split sidebar.twig into a separate file and
>   include it in layout.twig.

So:

> As explained above - it's a matter of design not programmability. It's
>   not about: I can achieve this same result using a different
>   programming technique, its about which usage is better design.

Answer (score 0):

Extend - Most of your pages share the same layout, so you create a base.twig as a parent, and each page extends that layout.twig. So the parent is the generic and the child is the specific.

Include - You notice that your layout.twig is bit cluttered and you would like to modularize it, so you split sidebar.twig into a separate file and include it in layout.twig.

Use - Your navbar goes on every page, so you create a nav.html.twig file and use it in your base.twig, adding a nav block.